# Javascript equivalent of PHP's "print"

Tags: javascript, php

If I have some PHP HTML that reads like this:

```
<html> I am feeling <?php print urldecode($_GET["emotion"]);?> today!</html>
```

and Get's "emotion" in URL title is "Happy", the HTML renders "I am feeling Happy today!".

---

Now, migrating away from PHP, how do I do this with javascript?

In Javascript I have a variable `$emotion = "Happy";` so what Javascript goes inbetween the script tags below (where there are currently asterisks********)

```
<html> I am feeling <script>*********************</script> today!</html>
```

Comment: And is the 'emotion' still to be found in the URL, as a GET parameter? Have you managed to make a start on this problem at all? And it might not be a good idea to migrate to a language that you don't know. By all means experiment, and learn, but leave migration for later. Php and JavaScript cover different ground.

Comment: @DavidThomas ???? Is this not "experiment / learn"? Hahah, I simply posted this as I am learning.

Comment: It may well be, yes; but 'migrating' is present-tense (a thing you are doing now), whereas if this is learning, then migration (future-tense) is a thing you will do in the future. Which makes more sense.

Comment: @DavidThomas hahaha that word "Migrating" had to do with my asking of the question, I wasn't saying that I was "now migrating away", I was saying, here is my example in PHP, now, migrating away from THAT example, here is my example in JS

Comment: document.write(emotion); ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easily by putting an element where you want the text to change, then accessing that element by it's id.

```js
$emotion = "Happy";
var e = document.getElementById('emotion');
e.innerHTML = $emotion;
```

```html
I am feeling <span id="emotion"></span> today!
```